# rightsquigarrow and leadsto

Tags: arrows

It seems I can't use `rightsquigarrow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\rightsquigarrow$
\end{document}
```

Gives me `Undefined control sequence` as does `leadsto`.

Where is this defined?

Answer (score 1):

As with many other interesting symbols, it's defined by

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
```